# Unable to send base64 image to server from android

Tags: java, php, android, base64

I explored many questions related to this issue but nothing solved my problem.
I am sending base64 encoded image in android and sending it to the server but that encoded string is unable to reach the Godaddy server.

What I've tried:

- Encoded Image to base64
- Decoding Image in PHP
- Log.d("showEncodedImageString", image); // Showing correctly

I followed the same code for my localhost using wampserver and it worked like a charm. But unable to send the imageString to a live server. It is like whenever I send this encoded string, php crashes somehow. I don't know. It should through back an echo statement which I am showing there as error but no it doesn't throwback anything.

Java Code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(1024, 1024).getBitmap();
                    String encodedImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);

                    HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    postData.put("image", "-" + encodedImage );

                    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(actCtx, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {
                                Toast.makeText(actCtx, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                /*Picasso.with(actCtx).load(SERVER_ADDRESS + loggedInEmail + ".jpeg").into(imageProfileIv);*/
                                dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    });
                    task.execute("http://fatappstudios.com/Webservices/Junaid/QuoteMedia/db_image_upload.php");
                    task.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IOException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ProtocolException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UnsupportedEncodingException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

PHP Code (try 1):

```
$name = $_POST["image"];

     try {
       echo $name;
     } catch(Exception $e) {
       echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
     }
```

PHP Code (try 2):

```
$name = $_POST["image"];
     echo $name;
```

If I simple echo "abc" and send any value but the encodedImage, it will show the abc string. So I am sure that db is connecting perfectly.

Please find a solution for me :(

P.S: For the time being. I even set all of the folders permissions on server to 777 so there is not issue of permission I assume.

Comment: *whenever I send this encoded string, php crashes...*, check your server's error log.

Comment: If you send the same request via postman you have the same result?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul It basically seems like it is crashing. It is not crashing though. Still let me check the server's error.

Comment: @jonathanrz Sorry I don't understand. What is POSTMAN? you mean POST method?

Comment: @user3314639 postman is a client to make post request, but you can use curl, wget or anything like that. Just repeat the request to check if your problem is in the android side or the server side.

Comment: @jonathanrz Yes it is working fine. Thanks! This tool is great. Never knew of this before. Yes it is working fine. Image has been uploaded when I sent the encoded String to php and previewed it. So it means that there is some problem with my code. But how come that same code, I mean exactly same code is working for my localhost(wamp)?

Comment: @user3314639 can you log in your server the request body that came from postman and the request that came from Android?

Comment: There is nothing much to log. I echo'd "Success"

if(file_put_contents("upload/demoimg.jpeg", base64_decode($image)) != false){
 echo "Uploaded";
}else{
 echo "Error";
}

It echo'd Success from postman. And in android it doesn't echo anything. I don't know why. It doesn't even echo error. It returns empty string so the toast is empty